# Tensorflow autocomplete in pycharm

Tags: python, tensorflow

I started to user tensorflow on pycharm and i discovered that there is not auto completion 
is it possible to add it

Comment: no because my pycharm complete numpy commands

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i think you might want to use this format to import it:

```
import tensorflow as tf
....
#usage
tf.keras.callbacks.—
tf.keras.optimizers.—
```

The above should fix it for you.

Answer (score 1):

You can fix it by replacing:

```python
import tensorflow.keras
```

with:

```python
import tensorflow.python.keras
```

Answer (score 0):

This issue is solved in PyCharm 2021.2.4

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).